# Add incremental values following an id

Tags: python, pandas

`I'm trying to add incremetal values for each id in this pandas dataframe
initial table

```
id col1   col2
1   0.12     10 
1   0.23     20
1    1.1     30
2   0.25     10
2    2.1     20
2    1.2     30
```

what i want to acheive

```
id  col1   col2
1   0.12     10 
1   0.23     20
1    1.1     30
1      0     40
1      0     50
2   0.25     10
2    2.1     20
2    1.2     30
2      0     40
2      0     50
```

i tried :

```
def func(row):
    for i in row["id"]:
        for j in range(40,50+1,10):
            row["id"] = i
            row["col1"] = 0
            row["col2"] = j

df = df.apply(lambda row:func(row))
```

but this raise an error that id doesn't exist
`KeyError: 'id'`

Comment: You should use [`iterrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/17200348) to iterate over rows in your dataframe.

Comment: I would do this if I were you. Just copy and paste the code section.

    sets = []
    for id in set(df['id']):
        for j in range(40, 50 + 1, 10):
            s = pd.Series({
                'id': id,
                'col1': 0,
                'col2': j
            })
            sets.append(s)

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(sets)
    df = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a *loop*, you can approach this by using a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) :

```
N = 50 # <- adjust here the limit to reach

gr = df.groupby("id", as_index=False).count()
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([gr["id"], range(10, N+10, 10)], names=["id", "col2"])

out = (df.set_index(["id", "col2"]).reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()[df.columns])​
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
   id  col1  col2
0   1  0.12    10
1   1  0.23    20
2   1  1.10    30
3   1  0.00    40
4   1  0.00    50
5   2  0.25    10
6   2  2.10    20
7   2  1.20    30
8   2  0.00    40
9   2  0.00    50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `id` and append values to needed columns via pandas concatenation:

```
df_to_append = pd.DataFrame([[0,40],[0,50]], columns=['col1','col2'])
df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x, df_to_append], ignore_index=True))\
        .reset_index(drop=True).fillna(method='ffill')
```

---

```
    id  col1  col2
0  1.0  0.12    10
1  1.0  0.23    20
2  1.0  1.10    30
3  1.0  0.00    40
4  1.0  0.00    50
5  2.0  0.25    10
6  2.0  2.10    20
7  2.0  1.20    30
8  2.0  0.00    40
9  2.0  0.00    50
```